# Get queryset object from child to append to parent queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the below models

```
class Order(models.MOdel):
  order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  ...

class OrderLink(models.Model):
  link_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
  linked_order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='linked_order_links', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  original_order = models.ForeignKey(
    Order, related_name='original_order_links', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default=None
  )

orders = order_models.Order.objects.filter()
```

I have `orders` `queryset`. Lets say I have got a parent `order` I need to find all the child orders from `OrderLink` and append to the `orders` `queryset`. How can I achieve that?
`linked_order` is the parent order and `original_order` is the child. So it will be in the format, P1C1, P1C2 etc. So finally in the `orders` I need [P1, C1, C2]. All orders whether it is parent or child refers to `Order` table.

Comment: `[link.original_order for link in order.linked_order_links.all()]` will give you all the `original_order`s of `order`

Comment: @bdbd `order.linked_order_links.all()` This gives an empty queryset. Where `order` is `orders[0]` right?

Comment: Yes `order` can be `orders[0]` if `orders` is a non-empty queryset. If `linked_order_links.all()` returns empty, that means it has no child